# Place one image under another in ngFor list Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a list of elements (images), which looks like 4x4 grid (length of array is 16, so I have 16 images).

```
<ul id="thumbnailsList">
  <li *ngFor="let key of array" >
    <img  [src]="img" class="tn">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
ul { padding:0; width:780px; margin:20px auto}
li { display:inline;}
.tn{
  margin:2px 2px;
  box-shadow:#999 1px 1px 3px 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 191px;
  height: 146px;

}
```

And I have this view for now: 
[image: Grid]

As next, I would like to place another images (another Grid - Grid 2) , each element from which will completely cover each image from first Grid.

I found this solution http://jsfiddle.net/uS7nw/2/ which what I need, but I can't implement it right in the Angular - I played a lot around with CSS, but each time it doesn't work.

So, essentially, it should look like

```
<ul id="thumbnailsList">
  <li *ngFor="let key of array" >
    <img  [src]="img" class="tn">
    <img  [src]="img2" class="secondImg">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Could you please help me to adjust CSS? PS. I don't need dynamically conditional binding like  `<img  [src]="option == true? img : img2">`, but I need exactly 2 images one on top of another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
ul { padding:0; width:780px; margin:20px auto}
li { 
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

li, li img {
  width: 191px;
  height: 146px;
}

.tn, .secondImg {
  position: absolute;
  margin:2px 2px;
  box-shadow:#999 1px 1px 3px 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

The images are positioned absolute within in `li`, so they sit on top of each other.

You can see a StackBlitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dykmxm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

You can add a z-index property to either `.tn` or `.secondImage` if you want to control which one sits on top

Answer (score 0):

First, your angular code should like this:

```
<ul id="thumbnailsList">
  <li *ngFor="let key of array" >
    <img  [src]="key" class="tn">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Not this:

```
<ul id="thumbnailsList">
  <li *ngFor="let key of array" >
    <img  [src]="img" class="tn">
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you want two image, one top of another, you can use bootstrap template

```
class row
      Class col-md-12
      class col-md-12
```